# JMeter TPS is not consistent as shown is TPS Graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Ran test with 50 concurrent users. Targetted TPS : 10
But TPS graph is showing result in zigzag manner its not consistent while test was ran fine without any error. Achieved TPS throughout the test 8.1/sec

Case 01) Ran test with timer 
Constant Timer :  5 sec

Case 02) Ran test with Ultimate thread group only

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The actual throughput depends on many factors, the main ones are:

1. JMeter should have enough headroom to operate in order to reach/maintain the target throughput. If JMeter cannot send requests fast enough even if application is not overloaded you will not be able to get the amount of TPS you want. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if a single JMeter engine cannot conduct the load you need you will have to consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)
2. Application response time is high. Given 50 concurrent users and target throughput of 10 requests per second you will only be able to achieve this only if application response time is less or equal to 5 seconds. If application response time will be higher - the throughput will be proportionally lower. The next steps would be:

   - try increasing the number of threads (virtual users). It's better to switch to the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination as they can be [connected](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so Concurrency Thread Group would be able to add more threads if current amount is not enough in order to reach/maintain the desired throughput
   - set up monitoring of your application using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) and [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to identify the bottleneck and determine the root cause of the application response time being above 5 seconds

Comment: Hi,Agree with your suggestion but in my case response time was not more, Still TPS graph was not consistent. Response time was 1.2 sec.

Comment: If we have multiple transaction in one T.G then how can we achieve pacing for TPS calculation or regulate the hits/sec.